# Overlapping HTML Markup

Tags: html, css

I would like to have three numbers (or words or whatever) with the first two surrounded by a red box and the second two surrounded by a green box.  So the boxes will overlap.  Is this possible in html/css?  I have a semi-legal attempt in the snippet which hopefully gets across what I want, though of course it doesn't work.  If possible I would like to avoid absolute positioning or anything like that as I really want to use these elements to mark up the text, and plan to read that markup back later.

```css
.red {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    padding: 4px;
}
.green {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
1 2 3                              <br /><br />
<span class="red">1 2</span> 3     <br /><br />
1 <span class="green">2 3</span>   <br /><br />
<span1 class="red"">1 <span2 class="green">2</span1> 3</span2>
```

This is approximately I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're going for here, even with the example you provided.  Could you draw what you want in paint and show us an image?

Comment: I think he wants to the number 2 to be a 'shared' element in two 'sets'.  And visually show the intersection.

Comment: If you phrased the question as 'how do I overlap divs that have borders shown'...it might yield different approaches to the answer.

Comment: @slime I see what you're saying, but what I'd really like to do is have the markup indicate the overlapping, like it does in the (non-working) sample snippet I included.  I think this just isn't possible in html, but I'd love to have someone show me a decent way.  Overlapping divs really doesn't capture what I'm looking for, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to deliberately break the XML format in your XHTML. And have the browser interpret the borders on elements correctly? It was common back in the day with things like `<b class="red"">1 <u class="green">2</b> 3</u>` and you'll see that is 'closer' to what you want but the browsers now a days fill in these gaps in display and force the proper foratting when adding the CSS. So you're left with having to do CSS hacks...

sorry it seems that :first-of-type and :last-of-type don't like to be added to 2 classes like .red.green:first-of-type so I had to add them in as `first` and `last` in the classes

(You can find the overlap by seeing which elements have both classes)

```css
     .numbersContainer {
       position: relative;
       margin: 12px;
     }
     .red {
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-bottom-style: solid;
       border-color: red;
       padding: 4px;
     }
     .green {
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-bottom-style: solid;
       border-color: green;
     }
     .red.green:before {
       content: " ";
       position: absolute;
       z-index: -1;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-bottom-style: solid;
       border-color: green;
       padding: 4px;
     }
     .red.green {
       position: relative;
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-bottom-style: solid;
       border-color: red;
       padding: 4px;
     }
     .numbersContainer .red:first-of-type {
       border-left-style: solid;
     }
     .numbersContainer .red:last-of-type {
       border-right-style: solid;
     }
     .numbersContainer .green:first-of-type {
       border-left-style: solid;
     }
     .numbersContainer .green:last-of-type {
       border-right-style: solid;
     }
     .first {
       border-left-style: solid;
     }
     .last {
       border-right-style: solid;
     }
     .red.green.first {
       border-left-style: none;
     }
     .red.green.first:before {
       border-left-style: solid;
     }
     .red.green.last {
       border-right-style: solid;
     }
     .red.green.last:before {
       border-right-style: none;
     }
```

```html
<div class="numbersContainer">
  1 2 3
</div>
<div class="numbersContainer">
  <span class="red">1 2</span> 3
</div>
<div class="numbersContainer">
  1 <span class="green">2 3</span> 
</div>
<div class="numbersContainer">
  <span class="red">1 </span><span class="red green first last">2</span><span class="green">3</span>
</div>
<div class="numbersContainer">
  <span class="red">1 </span><span class="red green first">2</span><span class="red green">3</span><span class="red green">4</span><span class="red green last">5</span><span class="green">6</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it is not very good coding style. If you change the text, you must also change the padding and margin of `.green`.

```css
.red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 16px;
}
.green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 24px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="red">1 2</span><span class="green">3</span>
```

Comment: This will break as soon as a different font or content is used (for example single letters instead of numbers).

Comment: Thats true, I added this seconds before to my post :)

Comment: Yeah, not really what I was looking for, but it does get the visual representation right.  I'll give you an upvote later, but I'm hoping someone will come along with a real solution.

Comment: I think there is no real solution ; ) I am still trying but it doesnt work as it should

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest i can get:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
body {
  padding: 10px;
  }
body:hover {
  background: blue;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
.one {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
.two {
  background: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  outline: 2px solid green;
  z-index: 2;
}
.three {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  z-index: 10000;
  outline: 2px #FFF solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="one">1</span><span class="two">2</span><span class="three">3</span>
```

It could also be possible using multiple pseudo-elements and absolute positioning, but there is no solution like you need. This is caused by the type of XML (HTML is XML), that two elements must not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure CSS solution:

```css
span {
  font: 1em monotype;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -0.4em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span>1 2 3</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Exmaple Negative value of margin-xxxx**

```css
.red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="red">1 2</div>
  <div class="green">3</div>
</div>
```

What i did: i made 2 inline-block (same line), use a negative margin to get 3 in 2 and 1 block and put this all 1 overlayer div.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS solution that stays together with different sized horizontal and vertical content, and does not use positioning. It uses CSS borders along with box-shadow, to create the multiple borders. Then CSS display:table-cell is used on the divs.

Using CSS table styles to create a relationship between the divs has several benefits. If the divs contain various amounts of content, the vertical height of each div will match, and the overall size can be adjusted (fluid %, or fixed pixel).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/da5b7h5L/

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row:
}
div {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
}
.right {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 0px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
}
.center {
  padding: 4px;
  border-top: 2px solid green;
  border-right: 0px solid green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 2px red;
}
.left {
  border-top: 2px solid green;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-left: 0px solid green;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="right">
      Here is a line of text
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <p>Paragraph 1 - Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2 - Maecenas semper facilisis diam. Phasellus placerat ante vitae dolor ornare sodales.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/abMA5gE.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```